# IIS Working Redirect Regex, but not passing values?

Tags: regex, cakephp, iis, url-rewriting

Really odd issue.  This is the regex I want to use:

```
<match url="^c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[?]((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&amp;amp;=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&amp;amp;=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&amp;amp;;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/c/?campaignid={R:1}&amp;listid={R:2}&amp;emailid={R:3}&amp;forward={R:4}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

which will be called like this:

```
http://mydomain/c/1/1/1/?http://redirecturl
```

But using the above regex, CakePHP is complaining that campaign/list/email are all blank.  Here is what is "odd", the below works, passing the values I want:

```
^c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)
```

It passes campaign/list/email Id values.  But when I add on the regex for the URL, they are all blanked out!?!

The "test" in IIS regex tester says that it is valid regex.

Comment: can you provide the full url we are parsing?

Comment: I'm currently just testing with http://mydomain/c/1/1/1/?http://google.com

Comment: something like http://regex101.com/r/sE7qQ3 is what we are testing?

Comment: looks like the issue is with the beginning of string declaration `^`

Comment: but the second example I gave works.. domain/c/1/1/1/

Comment: something interesting I tried, made rewrite rule: /c/?forward=http://google.com, and it still said forward is undefined.  does that mean an issue with cakephp?

Comment: someone suggested maybe the URL wasn't escaped.  so I tried {URLEncode:{R:1}}, still not working :(